# Displaying notifications on iOS device handled by a Ruby on Rails web application

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an iOS app that needs to have notifications display every time any user of that app does something like send another user a message. What I have currently is a working Ruby on Rails and Android app. The Rails app notifies Firebase when a notifiable activity occurs like so:

```
    if active_time.save
            fcm = FCM.new("AIzaSyDhMXi3797t2oZMxOTo-Nph8IoypRL8Ooc")
            registration_ids = Array.new
            for user in group.users do
                if  not user.token.nil?
                  registration_ids.push(user.token)
                end
            end
            options = {data: {score: "123"}, notification: {body:"Active time added to " + group.name, title: "Groupsync"}}
            response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)


            active_time.delay(run_at: active_time.start.getutc).send_group_live_notification
```

What I'm unsure about is how to get my iOS client to notice these activities and display notifications like its Android counterpart. I have set up FCM on the iOS client and am able to send notifications, just not sure what the next step is in terms of making the link.

EDIT: I should mention for the above piece of is controlled by my iOS client through HTTP POST requests

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using a service line OneSignal. It's free and you can set a lot of platforms there, between android, ios and web browsers. For ios you're gonna need a push certificate from apple (see more here: https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522). Once you set your configs for android and ios, for example, you can use their api and send the notifications using their ruby gem, for example (https://github.com/tbalthazar/onesignal-ruby).

Good luck!

Comment: If I understand you're suggesting I use OneSignal instead of Firebase? I have actually got a significant amount of the project set up and working with Firebase cloud messenger, including all of the certificate work associated with Apple Developer. The only thing I can't figure out is how to get my iOS device to display the FCM messages that my Ruby on Rails web application is already taking care of and sending to the android device.

Comment: No, you still will need firebase cloud messaging, but you'll get a token for it and configure it directly on OneSignal, so OneSignal will handle it for you, and you'll just have to worry about the OneSignal service. Take a look in this article, think it will make it clear: http://androidbash.com/android-push-notification-service-using-onesignal/